# SMTP between two linux machines

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail, mutt

Is there are way to use SMTP to message pass between two linux servers? Even if they are not SMTP servers, I was wondering if I could just use SMTP to communicate between servers.

I have two ubuntu servers: 111.111.111.111 and 222.222.222.222. On each server I have set up user accounts master and node, respectively.

On 111.111.111.111, the file `/var/spool/mail/master` exists.
On 222.222.222.222, the file `/var/spool/mail/node` exists.

---

On 111.111.111.111, `/etc/hosts` has the line `222.222.222.222 node.us`
On 222.222.222.222, `/etc/hosts` has the line `111.111.111.111 master.us`

---

Assume that `sudo iptables --list` shows that port 25 is being accepted from all addresses

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Could I get something like this to work from the `master` (`111.111.111.111`) server?

```
sendmail -s "subject" node@node.us < sometextfile.txt
```

or some equivalent usint `sendEmail` or `mutt`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

James -

Ideally you should be able to do what you are suggesting. You need to make sure that DNS resolution is working for those hosts files though - i did a quick test of this and I kept getting undeliverable for no AAAA (ipv6) record being found.

Also, the command to send you message should use the mail command instead of the sendmail, like this:

```
mail -s "subject" node@node.us < sometextfile.txt
```